# Saving Entity containing fields of the same type - Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have an entity which contains two fields consisting of the same entity - call them Robot, Human:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "robots")
public class Robot
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "rel_robots_humans", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "robot_id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "human_id")})
    private Set<Human> humans;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "special_human_id")
    private Human specialHuman;
}
```

Both entities equals and hashCode are based on each's unique id.

I have a web page in which both humans and specialHuman of a specific robot can be edited and changed.

Now, I'm trying to just change and save specialHuman's value to a different existing and valid human from inside robot's humans set. Here is the Data Transfer Object received from client:

```
public class RobotDTO
{
    @NotNull
    private Integer id;

    private Set<HumanDTO> humans;

    private HumanDTO specialHuman;

    //getters and setters
}
```

HumanDTO consists only id the same way RobotDTO has. Both equals and hashCode are well implemented and based on the non-nullable-id.

Using DozerBeanMapper, I'm mapping specialHuman into the fetched matching robot:

```
ActionResult<Robot> saveRobot(Robot pRobot, RobotDTO pRobotDTO)
{
    dozerBeanMapper.map(pRobotDTO, pRobot);

    return ActionResultFactory.fromNullable(entityManager.merge(pRobot));
}
```

**And finally, here is the problem**

Hibernate gets confused, and tries to insert the special human into "rel_robots_humans" table instead of just updating it in robots table.
(I checked ten times that the list of humans received without any changes and that the specialHuman was set to the fetched Robot by dozer appropriately)

When I change the type of specialHuman from Human entity to another entity, say for example, Alien, (with the same structure and fields), hibernate does the update correctly.

I tried really hard to search for this issue but didn't manage to find any info regarding it.

I'm using: Hibernate 4.3.10.Final (I tried to upgrade to 5.0.1.Final but the bug still occurs), Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE

Any help would be much appreciated and will award the helper with a place in the matrix of paradise.

Comment: I saw your DTO and your entity is basically the same, i would try to send/receive from the view the original entity, and save it directly. Is how usually i work, no need to write extra objects when everything i need is in the main entity. I also would add the cascadeType=ALL

Comment: My real Entity contains much more fields than the DTO. I didnt specify them since they are not part of the problem. And if it is the owning side of the ManyToMany the cascade is done automatically so there is no need to specify the cascadeType.

Comment: The humans collection shouldn't interfere with specialHuman even though they are the same entity type. Is there any exception thrown on the merge function, or is the specialHuman a new object (e.g. unsaved)? Did you use a different human object for the specialHuman other than any member of the humans set, or what happens if you remove the humans mapping?

Comment: @SimonL - First, thanks for your comment. The exception I'm getting is SQLException: Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' when trying to set specialHuman to be one of the robot's humans. When I set specialHuman to be one which doesn't appear inside robot's humans it works perfectly. If I remove the humans mapping it works perfectly. I'm not setting specialHuman to be one of the humans "by reference", but fetching specialHuman and then setting its primary key (id) to be the chosen by client one.

Comment: @SimonL - furthermore, if specialHuman's current value doesn't appear in humans list, and I try to update it to a human which is inside humans - it works! Only the case when the current specialHuman is in humans and I'm trying to update to another human which is also in humans fails constantly

Comment: @aviad - Why did you have the PK violation error, the id is the single PK column in robots table, then the error might implicate the violation of PK in rel_robots_humans table. So can you post more detail of the exception with SQL and the Human class to show the mapping from Human to robot.

Comment: @SimonL - it is indeed a violation in rel robots humans table. Which is exactly the bug - instead of updating specialHuman, it tries to insert the selected human along with the parent robot to the wrong table and that row exists there. Anyway, I decided to manually bypass this by saving just the Id of the special human in robot. Thank you very much for your time anyway it is much appreciated. !